# Is it possible to load a .d.ts file in raw form in the vite dev server?

Tags: vite

In my app, I have monaco editor that can take .d.ts file to provide API auto-completition. I tried file?url, file?inline, file?raw and and a combination of them and none of them gave me the .d.ts file in its raw format. They are always getting transformed by vite dev server. Currently I have two options 1) Use .d.ts.txt extension or 2) load it from a separate server. None of these are ideal if it is possible to load it as is without transformation.